# SQL Query performance improvement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I want to get results from union of two tables with pagination, currently I'm using following query

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT Clients .id, Clients.Name 
      FROM Clients 
      INNER JOIN ClientPolicies ON ClientPolicies .client_id = Clients .id
    UNION
   SELECT c.id,c.Name 
      FROM ClientGroupPolicies cgp 
      JOIN `Groups` g ON g.id = cgp.client_group_id 
      JOIN GroupClients gc ON g.id = gc.groupId 
      JOIN Clients c ON c.id = gc.clientId) AS tb
    LIMIT 0,100
```

I'm getting correct results but can can do it in single query or improve it's performance.
Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
HERE is the query with EXIST

```
SELECT
    c2.id,
    c2.user
FROM
    Clients c2
WHERE
    EXISTS(
    SELECT
        ClientPolicies.client_id
    FROM
        ClientPolicies
    WHERE
        ClientPolicies .client_id = c2.id )
    or EXISTS (
    SELECT
        gc.clientId
    FROM
        ClientGroupPolicies cgp
    JOIN Groups g on
        g.id = cgp.client_group_id
    JOIN GroupClients gc on
        g.id = gc.groupId
    WHERE
        gc.clientId = c2.id )
LIMIT 0,
10
```

**RESULT WITH UNION**

```
id|select_type |table         |partitions|type  |possible_keys   |key      |key_len|ref                         |rows|filtered|Extra                                             |
--|------------|--------------|----------|------|----------------|---------|-------|----------------------------|----|--------|--------------------------------------------------|
 1|PRIMARY     |<derived2>    |          |ALL   |                |         |       |                            |  14|   100.0|                                                  |
 2|DERIVED     |ClientPolicies|          |index |client_FK       |client_FK|5      |                            |   8|   100.0|Using where; Using index                          |
 2|DERIVED     |Clients       |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY         |PRIMARY  |4      |sdp.ClientPolicies.client_id|   1|   100.0|                                                  |
 3|UNION       |cgp           |          |ALL   |                |         |       |                            |   2|   100.0|Using where                                       |
 3|UNION       |g             |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY         |PRIMARY  |4      |sdp.cgp.client_group_id     |   1|   100.0|Using index                                       |
 3|UNION       |gc            |          |ALL   |clientId,groupId|         |       |                            |   3|   100.0|Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
 3|UNION       |c             |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY         |PRIMARY  |4      |sdp.gc.clientId             |   1|   100.0|                                                  |
  |UNION RESULT|<union2,3>    |          |ALL   |                |         |       |                            |    |        |Using temporary                                   |
```

**RESULT WITH EXIST**

```
id|select_type       |table         |partitions|type  |possible_keys   |key      |key_len|ref           |rows|filtered|Extra                                             |
--|------------------|--------------|----------|------|----------------|---------|-------|--------------|----|--------|--------------------------------------------------|
 1|PRIMARY           |c2            |          |ALL   |                |         |       |              | 159|   100.0|Using where                                       |
 3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|gc            |          |ref   |clientId,groupId|clientId |4      |sdp.c2.id     |   1|   100.0|                                                  |
 3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|g             |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY         |PRIMARY  |4      |sdp.gc.groupId|   1|   100.0|Using index                                       |
 3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|cgp           |          |ALL   |                |         |       |              |   2|    50.0|Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
 2|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|ClientPolicies|          |ref   |client_FK       |client_FK|5      |sdp.c2.id     |   1|   100.0|Using index                                       |
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And note that as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Since you only select fields from client i think you wouldn't need union but use outer joins and where clauses

Comment: `where exists(Clientpolicy-query) or exists(ClientGroupPolicies-query)` would do the job, too

Comment: @Turo I have updated my question, please check which one is better.

Comment: For the data that is there (small Policies-Tables) the Union approach is clearly better: the UNION worked on 2 rows and in the EXITS query it runs over the whole table to see wether there is or is not a policy

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Answer (score 0):

UNION ALL is faster than UNION. Also in future if you need to use WHERE Clause, you must use it cleverly as WHERE clause on the result of union is an expensive query. Instead you can use it in your inner queries

Comment: I need distinct data. If I use union all then how will I get distinct data?

Comment: Should I use DISTINCT => `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM` ?